# How to plot series of results as number of iterations after I used Newton_system?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following results :

```
v =
    7.8053  959.5985
    6.1820  481.3263
    4.9794  242.2347
    4.0829  122.7578
    3.4079   63.1224
    2.8962   33.4578
    2.5118   18.8560
    2.2380   11.9084
    2.0725    8.9597
    2.0086    8.0952
    2.0001    8.0012
    2.0000    8.0000
    2.0000    8.0000
```

Which I got them after I ran a function called `newton_system` for calculating , and I ran the input vector `[10,3]` on the follwoing `f(x,y)` :

```
y(1) = x(1)^3 - 5*x(1)^4 + x(2)^2 + 8;
y(2) = 2*x(1)^3 - x(2)^2 + 5*x(1)^2 + 5*x(2) - 12;
```

I ran 13 iterations , and now I want to plot a graph of the approximations as a function of the iterations (from 1 to 13) , can someone please explain how to do that ?

FYI please notice that as I progress with the iterations , we converge to  `2.0000    8.0000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `plot` command:

```
plot(v(:,1),v(:,2),'-o') %# plot the line with circles for the x,y values
hold on,plot(2,8,'+r') %# add a red cross for the solution
xlim([0 8]) %# modify x-axes limits so that the plot looks a bit better
```

Use the zoom button on the figure menu to zoom into the area around the solution.

[image]

Comment: Thanks , just one thing , how do I combine the 3 command together to get the exact same graph ?